# Graph algorithms on google earth

Tags: google-maps, graph, maps, google-earth

I'm very new at this subject, so my apologies if my question is trivial.
I want to take a part of a google map or google earth (at a location that interests me) and I wish to run some graph algorithm on it. For example, I want to randomly choose several coordinates around the location, construct a graph between them, where each node holds the real coordinates, (lets assume complete graph) and find the shortest path between two given points (using Dijkstra). My question is very basic: How do I take the map/view in GE and convert it to a graph (to be processed in C# or any other language).

To be more clear: I want to look at some location in GE. In this location I will mark some points (not necessarily points that are marked in the 'standard' maps. It may be an 'open area'. The points are my own choises - randomly chosen). I want to construct a graph between these points, choose two points and find the shortest path between them. It is easy to download the jpg of the location throuhg GE, but it doesn't help me, since I need to have the coordinates of each marked point.

Thanks in advance,
  Itzik

Answer (score 0):

You can not.

Google does not allow extracting information of the transportation network to use it anywhere else (and/or imposes heavy restrictions in their [terms & conditions](https://maps.google.com/help/terms_maps.html)).

Similar restrictions exist for Bing maps, Here maps, Apple maps, ESRI basemaps, and others.

If your question had been something like...

> Where can I download/access the transportation network for a given city/area, in such a form and conditions that I can build a routing graph based on that data for my own purposes?

...then the answer is "depends on where you live". Research local mapping agencies and ask for road centerlines. A safer bet would be to use OpenStreetMap data, as it's worldwide and has no restrictions on usage.

As you are "very new in this subject", I suggest start by researching https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing, https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data, https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts/ for data, and http://pgrouting.org/ for storage and basic algorithms.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I already looked at openstreetmap, and although it answers some of my needs, I still need to be able to look at the image of the area and process it.  What I actually probably need is to be able to download jpg file/s of the the area and have the coordinates (I guess it should be enough to have one point and size or two opposite points. The rest I will do by my self).

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "look at the image of the area and process it"? Please edit your original question to make this clear.